# shapeAppearance in Material Component FloatingActionButton causes a crash

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-jetpack, material-components-android, material-components

```
E/OpenGLRenderer: resultIndex is -1, the polygon must be invalid!
A/OpenGLRenderer: Error: Spot pair overflow!!! used 38, total 22
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 11996 (hwuiTask1)
```

Using shapeAppearance attribute causes a crash.

This is the FAB in XML

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:onClick="@{() -> callback.add(viewModel.plant)}"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.Sunflower.FAB"  <--
            app:isGone="@{viewModel.isPlanted}"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus" />
```

Below is the style for shapeAppearance,

```
<style name="ShapeAppearance.Sunflower.FAB" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">30dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">30dp</item>
</style>
```

This solves the crash.

```
    <style name="ShapeAppearance.Sunflower.FAB" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item> <--
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item> --
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

I need to know the reason behind it and how to solve it while using the same corner style.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/CustomShapeOVerlay"
      />
```

And in the style (without defining the `parent`)

```
  <style name="CustomShapeOVerlay" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">30dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">30dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Nope. Not working. Are you aware of the reason behind the crash?

Comment: Try the 1.1.0-alpha10. Sorry but no idea about the crash, the log doesn't contain useful info.

Comment: Yea, actually that's all I am getting in the logcat.

Comment: @Ashrafpatel Try to use an empty project with a very simple theme and only the fab with the shapeAppearanceOverlay.

Comment: If you can file a bug at https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues with a sample application which demonstrates this crash, that would be useful.

Comment: @CameronKetcham here it is https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/661

Comment: @Ashrafpatel thanks for the feedback. Quite curious that I am able to run with the 30dp. In any case I've added the info reported in the issue because it can help the community.

Comment: It's actually hard to reproduce sometimes. I had to keep scrolling a bunch of times in order to reproduce it. Surprisingly after testing for a while, none of the solutions seems to be working.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/3c3ac61c9126a7b97da7e10324be163c11257e53

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti It doesn't overwrite the `cornerRadius` attribute though, which I have set on `materialButtonStyle`

Comment: @Dr.jacky The `FloatingActionButton` doesn't have a `cornerRadius` attribute.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti You're right. My specific issue is I have a `MaterialButton` and `materialButtonStyle` which has `cornerRadius`. So, my `cornerSizeTopLeft` in `shapeAppearanceOverlay` using directly on the `MaterialButton` doesn't affect. And button is fully rounded.

Comment: The solution to my problem mentioned in the comment: I had to pass `@null` to `cornerRadius`.